# File permissions with l3build ctan

Tags: l3build

I'm trying use `l3build ctan` to prepare a `.zip` file appropriate for CTAN upload.  In particular, I'd like the resulting `.zip` file to meet the file permissions requirements for CTAN (at https://ctan.org/file/help/ctan/CTAN-upload-addendum#filepermissions). The relevant part is:

> Files submitted to CTAN are obviously meant for publication. This implies that they should be “world readable”. (In fact, exaggerated “privacy” of file permissions can lead to serious complications in the installation process.)

Unfortunately, I do use a more restrictive `umask` myself, so I cannot rely on things "just working".

I examined three possibilities for trying to deal with this. First, try to handle it on `zip`'s side, controlling `zipopts`, but I couldn't find any option there which could do this. Second, see if some kind of "hook" was provided by `l3build` itself, but I also couldn't find one. Third, I considered building a bash script which would do both things and pass it to `l3build` as `zipexe`. Alas, the function `dirzip` in `l3build-ctan.lua` does not simply pass a list of files to `zipexe`, but builds exclusions in place alongside with other arguments beyond those of `zipopts`. So it does not seem to be trivial to get what is actually being passed to `zipexe` and feed it to `chmod` (perhaps there is a way, I don't see it).

That given, how can I ensure the `.zip` files prepared by `l3build ctan` comply with the CTAN upload requirement of being "world readable"?

Comment: We've never had a request in this area, not least because on Windows such issues never arise :) I think this looks more like a feature request for `l3build` than a question here.

Comment: It has occurred to me that at present some aspects of the zip support are ... suboptimal

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for your comment. I'm new to the process, so I was in doubt whether the fault is on my side. Would https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues be the correct place to make such a request?

Comment: Yes, that would be it: the only (easy) way to address the question is for me, Marcel or Paulo to adjust the code and release it :)

Comment: @JosephWright Feature request made: https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/197.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be easy: that I can see, there's no way to tell `zip` to ignore file attributes

Comment: @JosephWright Why not just run `chmod` (if OS has it) on the directories to be zipped?

Comment: Apparently, `tar` can handle file permissions "on the fly": https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414651. But then, arguments such as `-ll` and the exclusions are hard-coded in `l3build-ctan.lua`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128261/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-gusbrs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported and fixed upstream in https://github.com/latex3/l3build/pull/198, and now `l3build` ensures the CTAN file permissions requirements are met, independently of local `umask` settings.